# Gulp uglify error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, gulp-uglify

I have a React JavaScript project and I am using `gulp-uglify` on it.

Without uglifying, the project works fine.
However, when I uglify it, I get the following error:

```
[11:56:05] [Uglify] Error in plugin 'gulp-uglify'
Message:
    C:\Users\project\trunk\app.js: Unexpected token punc «}», expected punc «:»
Details:
    lineNumber: 3858
```

However, the error appears in an uglified file which I can't read.

How can I find out what this error is?

What is the most likely cause for it?

Comment: What is in `C:\Users\project\trunk\app.js` on line 3858 and around it?

Comment: It seems that this is a temporary file which is not saved if `gulp-uglify` finds an error. How can I make `gulp-uglify` save the file anyway?

Comment: It depends on your gulp file. `app.js` is probably output of some previous task in the gulp pipeline, you can just `gulp.dest` it before uglifying, just to look into.